# Using node.js alone or together with other technology like Rails, Asp.net, etc

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, node.js, web, architecture

I want to build a web application where it has about 40 pages. Most of these pages involve something like CRUD operations on a Database. However, a **couple of pages** must have the capability to do some work in real-time.

So, I am considering two options:

1 - Doing all the web app in Node.js;
2 - Using Node.js just in the couple of pages that the real-time job is required. And the rest of the app using some regular backend technology like Rails, Asp.net, Java EE, etc.

**What would you recommend to me?

What option would you pick if you were in my place?**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use cases, I see no reason to cause yourself pain by mixing technologies. Doing pages that are mostly doing CRUD operations isn't hard in Node.js, so I'd just use it for the whole app.

Check out this post, you may find it helpful:[How to best create a RESTful API in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990544/how-to-best-create-a-restful-api-in-node-js)